# Is there a point of client-side validation of static info from a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, security, validation

My question is regarding the user input that is received form a html form and is static one(by 'static' - I mean information from things like select options, radio buttons, check boxes). Should i do a client-side validation as i assume that the user can change my html code with tools like firebug.

Example:

**my code:**

```
<select>
<option>public</option>
<option style="display:none">private</option>
</select>
```

**user's modification:**

```
<select>
<option>public</option>
<option selected >private</option>
</select>
```

Should I validate this input in JS or leave it for the server-side validation?
I know that the user can manipulate JS also so I see no point in doing this kind of validation in JS.

**My logic:**

1. As this is a static info an ordinary(the good guy) user won't mess with it and therefor there is no need to check it.
2. If an evil user want to mess with my code he probably will know how to mix not only the HTML code but also the JS code, so again - no need of client-side validation for static inputs.

So am I right or should always have the full specter of validation on the client-side.

PS:I'm asking only for the client side, I do always/as well a server-side validation of all the users inputs/

Comment: Don`t worry.Even if Client edits something,it is only going to be changed on his/her local machine and simple reload will again bring back your original HTML output. Client cannot make changes on the server(in context what you are talking about).

Don`t Worry.Carry on With you Project.Fearlessly.

Read some good books on client and server side programming languages.

Use javascript and Ajax with some Php to validate your code!!!

Comment: thanks @MESSIAH that's the kind of spirit I need :)

Comment: As usual, keep in mind the "sanity check" for client side validation -- if the user disabling JavaScript breaks your security model, then your security model is broken :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Always** validate your input server side.

It's *nice* to validate things in JavaScript because you can tell the user *early* that the input is incorrect.

A clever user can bypass any JavaScript constraint you place because you can always make your own requests.

---

From a time-efficiency point of view. It's not worth spending a lot of time trying to *help* the evil user by always trying to give a useful error message. If the server thinks input is invalid you can reply with `"invalid input"`. If your JavaScript validation is *good enough* a regular user should never run into that error.